# SCO Unix 5.0.5, Progress 7 - partly broken terminal view after virtualization

Tags: xterm, sco

I've got a problem with ancient app build in `SCO Unix 5.0.5` Server based on Progress 7 database after trying to virtualize environment. Problem is similar to messed up terminal after trying to cat or ls binary file.

In production everything is fine. We have bare metal 20yr (!) server with SCO Unix. App with the database engine and user config is on another, newer machine, shared by nfs_v2.
A user connects to the server by putty-telnet (xterm only) and after login, the app starts by default.

I've successfully installed SCO on VMware, mount shares and write initial config. Connecting by telnet and login starts the app. In an application, we have a print preview. When I want to see the preview, everything is okay. But if I want to see another page (by PgDn or cursor down), after 2 or 3 pages terminal is all messed up. Weird codename, similar to trying to view a binary file in normal Linux terminal. After exiting from print preview, everything is ok.

Contact with authors of the app is not possible. I'm looking for every hint I can get.

Comment: Could you have different terminal definitions on both machines? See some hints here: http://scofaq.aplawrence.com/FAQ_scotec6termtype.html

Comment: Last time I migrated legacy servers, I did not reinstall them, I made an image/clone of them by hand. As a last measure approach, and not knowing what customizations or hacks were done, I would try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Terminal definition give me hint to solution. I've checked SCO terminal definition in `/etc/termcap`, after that definition in Progress in `/usr/dlc7/protermcap`. I choose another than xterm, compatible terminal and change putty configuration in `Terminal ->Keyboard -> The Function keys and keypad -> VT100+` and `Connection -> Data -> Terminal-type string -> vt220`

Now display and look is ok, function keys like ESC and F1-F4 behave like in original setup.